# How stretch EditText in Android

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want to editText stretched up when there is a lot of text, and not hiding text. In layout.xml I have the height for layout.

Comment: Well show your xml file code that has the editText.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit short and weird but could android:layout_width="fill_parent" on the editText help?

Or you could provide more of your code.